# Jquery generate link from radio button with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, hyperlink, generated

Ive got an important question. I want to generate a hyper link. 
here is an example:

```
Radio group one:
[X] Black
[ ] White
Radio group two:
[ ] Black 
[X] White
[ ] Yellow
Radio group three:
[ ] Black 
[ ] White
[X] Red
```

This would be the result:

```
<a href="www.example.de/example/BLACK-SITE/WHITE-SITE/RED-SITE">My generated Link</a>
```

I hope you understand what I mean :) would be great to get any ideas how to fix this. Thank you kind regards, Nicole :)

Here is my Code so far:

```
     <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){



    $('#back1').change(function(){
        if(this.checked)
            $('#backimg1').show();
            $('#backimg2').hide();
            var back = '/schwarz-17'; 

    });

    $('#back2').change(function(){
        if(this.checked)
            $('#backimg1').hide();
            $('#backimg2').show();
            var back = '/weiss-18'; 

    });     



    $('#front1').change(function(){
        if(this.checked)
            $('#frontimg1').show();
            $('#frontimg2').hide();
            $('#frontimg3').hide();
            var back = '/teil-21'; 

    });

    $('#front2').change(function(){
        if(this.checked)
            $('#frontimg1').hide();
            $('#frontimg2').show();
            $('#frontimg3').hide();
            var back = '/halb-23'; 

    });

    $('#front3').change(function(){
        if(this.checked)
            $('#frontimg1').hide();
            $('#frontimg2').hide();
            $('#frontimg3').show();
            var back = '/ganz-26'; 
    });
});



 <a id="link" onclick="location.href=this.href+'?key='+back+front;return false;" href ="http://www.tronitechnik.de/duschen">
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried ? Do you expect us to do this markup for you ?

Comment: Sorry. Just edited so u can see what i allready tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 3 radio box with respectives id's : radio1, radio2, radio3 :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var link1 = "default1" ;
var link2 = "default2" ;
var link3 = "default3"
var baseLink = "www.example.de/example/" ;
var finalLink ;

$('#radio1').on('change', function() {
    link1 = $(this).val();
    changeLink();
});

$('#radio2').on('change', function() {
    link2 = $(this).val();
    changeLink();
});

$('#radio3').on('change', function() {
    link3 = $(this).val();
    changeLink();
});

function changeLink(){
    finalLink = baseLink + link1 + "/" + link2 + "/" + link3 ;
    $("#link").attr("href",finalLink);
}

}
```

I advise you to verify the link before doing the  `$("#link").attr("href",finalLink);`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH I GOT THE HOLE PROBLEM SOLVED :) <3